# Android AutoCompleteTextView: How to verify if a user has selected a suggested value or entered a new one?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How can I programmatically distinguish between the situation the user has selected one of the suggested values from the AutoCompleteTextView or entered a completely new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a boolean variable that you set to true when `onCommitCompletion` is called, and set to false when the value is changed manually (when `onKeyDown` is pressed for example).

Comment: It might still be though, that (for whatever reason) the user manually enters a value from the suggestion list. In that case your solution would not yield the desired result. Instead it would be better to match the input (when Focus is lost for instance) against the available suggestions